# How does one declare an array in VBScript?

Tags: arrays, vbscript

I used this in Excel and it works fine.

```
dim varScreen (0 to 2) as string
varScreen(0) = "sample 1"
varScreen(1) = "sample 2"
varScreen(2) = "sample 3"
```

I am trying to translate this array to VBScript but I keep getting this error:

```
Line: 14
Error: Expected ')'
```

I have tried various options, removed `as string`, `dim varScreen as array` but I still get the error.

What is the proper syntax?

Comment: There is a space between `varScreen` and `(0 to 2)`. There should **not** be.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

VBScript's (variables and) arrays can't be typed, so no "as Whatever". VBscript's arrays are zero-based, so no "(x To y)" but only "(z)" where z is the last index (not the size) of the array. In code:

```
>> Dim varScreen(2)
>> varScreen(0) = "sample 1"
>> varScreen(1) = "sample 2"
>> varScreen(2) = "sample 3"
>> WScript.Echo Join(varScreen, "|")
>>
sample 1|sample 2|sample 3
>>
```

Comment: What are the `>>` marks for? They make the code a bit harder to read.

Comment: ``>>`` is the prompt of my REPL.

Comment: I encountered similar problem by writing (1 To n), which works fine in vba, I just wanted my array to have base 1, so how can I realize base 1 not from 0? Thanks!

Comment: You can't have native base 1 arrays in VBScript. Just adapt your access code.

Answer (score 14):

You can also create arrays dynamically using the [`Array`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dsxhtazh(v=vs.84).aspx) function. Sometimes this is more convenient than assigning array elements separately.

```
Dim arr
arr = Array("sample 1", "sample2", "sample 3")
```

Comment: Or, if you want to have it all in a single line, use `Dim arr :
arr = Array("sample 1", "sample2", "sample 3")`.